# Warning on appSettings

Tags: vb.net

I've searched everywhere on how to get rid of this warning with no luck. I have added reference to my Module1.vb: Imports System.Configuration and I've tried:
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings. Still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
Dim sAttr As String
sAttr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("TITLE")

Console.WriteLine("The value of TITLE is: " & sAttr)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="TITLE" value="Mr"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am getting the warning on:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("TITLE")
```

Like I've said. I've Googled this warning and the only findings I am coming across are that I need to add reference to System.Configuration, which I have tried, and I still have the warning. I've also found that I need to add a reference to System.Configuration.dll but this statement is unnecessary and gives me a warning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: Okay, I figured out why I was getting a warning. I was putting the reference in the wrong project. (Silly me). But now, when I want to see the value of title, nothing is displayed. It should be like this in the console:

```
The value of TITLE is: Mr
```

Anyone know why the value or the key is not displaying? Thanks again! :)

Comment: for this you actually have to right click on references, and add a reference to System.Configuration.

Comment: I have done this. You make sure that System.Configuration is checked in the checkbox, correct?

Comment: ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is still giving me a warning.

Comment: When I change ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings to  sAttr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TITLE") warning does go away but when I Console.Writeline(sAttr) nothing is display but my value for TITLE is Mr in my config file.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this warning, instead of using ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings, you need to change it to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings as the ConfigurationSettings not used anymore.